# Return two string in toString function

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
@Entity
public class Person {

private Integer id = null;
private String name = null;
private String price = null;
private Date created = null;

// String Representation:
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
   // I want to return name and price 
}
```

I want to return `name` and `price` in toString function ? This is right to return more than one string in toString function. If you make relation in other's Entity ManyToMany ?

Please suggest me if I am doing right or wrong as I want to show these fields in other entity where I make relations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the `toString()` method returns a string-representation of the object and not the object's members themself. So if you need a representation of name and price you could do

```
return "Name: " + name + ", Price: " + price;
```

If you really want to receive the members `name` and `price` you should generate getters for those and use them in the caller.

Another possibility is to "wrap" the two strings in some sort of data class.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already created setter and getters for this. I want to know that this is better way more than two string return in toString function or any other better way ?

Comment: @sid The easiest way is to use the getter methods. It will be much more readable than anything else

Comment: Actually I make relation ManytoMany for this entity in my Plans Entity and when I show Plans entity with person fields then It's show only person name because I return in toString function only name and I want to show person name and person price .

Comment: @sid If you only want to SHOW the strings then it'll be fine to do just concatenate the strings like we all did in our answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
return name+" "+price;
```

You can create another method to return both.

you can return `String array` as well so that you don't need to split the string if you need to perform any operation on name and price.

Answer (score 1):

> This is right to return more than one string in toString function. If you make relation in other's Entity ManyToMany ?

That could be

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name :" +name + " Price : "+price;
}
```

If you still have more Objects related to it, just append in the last. So that you won't loose information.

Comment: @SURESH ATTA Thanks for answer.  So This is good way to return more than one string in toString function or any other better way ?

Comment: @sid Of course it is. Since you can't return any other Object, only a single String should be return. Hence build it and return.

Comment: @SURESH ATTA Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringBuilder` and build up your composed `String` efficiently from both the name, the price and whatever you want.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) the documentation.

Anyway, the response is no, you cannot send back two strings, but you can return a string that is a composition of the others.